# Setting header of CheckboxTableViewer

Tags: java, jface

The CheckboxTableViewer allows creation a single checklist.

But how do I put the header of such a column since the column itself is not created by a TableColumn.

```
    tableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, SWT.SINGLE| SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(0));
    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(1));
    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(2));
    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(3));
    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(4));
    tableViewer.add(checkListNames.get(5));

    final Table table = tableViewer.getTable();

    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    System.out.println(table.getColumnCount()); // this returns a zero

    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `TableLayout` and `TableViewerColumn` to define a column so you can set the header text.

The minimum code would be:

```
TableLayout layout = new TableLayout();

TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.LEAD);

col.getColumn().setText("Text");

layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(100));

table.setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: How do I then create a check column? CheckboxTableViewer allowed that to be created directly.

Comment: The check is part of the first column. This code works for a CheckboxTableViewer. Put the code just before the `setHeaderVisible` call

Comment: Well it worked, but I still have a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410695/layout-setting-for-a-jface-table) with the  scrollbar.